# How does disqus know who I am when I go to a website that I have never been to before?

Tags: cookies, disqus

When I go to a site that I have never been to before and it has Disqus installed, somehow Disqus knows who I am.

Cookies can only be read by the site that saved the cookie. If I have never been to a site before then it does not have a cookie to read and say "aha I know you".

How do they do it?

Comment: Disqus uses an iframe, with iframe you can set a cookie in a different domain.

Comment: Aha - that must be it - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They use cookies. Disqus most likely stores cookies of your session from their site when you authenticate yourself, so when you go on another site they still know its you. It's like how Facebook knows it's you on a site that has Facebook comments integrated.

Comment: No - browsers will not let cookies be set for another domain - that's why I asked the question.